# Why did curve in parcel fabric invert itself?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, parcel-fabric

I'm using the [Parcel Fabric](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-parcels/what-is-a-parcel-fabric-.htm) from ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1 and when I joined this parcel to the fabric, this curve inverted itself. The traverse grid is correct with a -55.00 radius. When unjoined, the parcel and the curve show up correctly. I've tried rejoining it, checking the joins of all the surrounding parcels, changing the radius to (+) to see if it would do the opposite, and regenerating parcel fabric on just this one parcel, and nothing has worked.

Why did the curve do this and how do I fix it?

[image: Joined parcel with inverted curve]

[image: Unjoined parcel with correctly oriented curve]

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/335740/why-did-curve-in-parcel-fabric-invert-itself?noredirect=1#comment547652_335740) the asker also:

> Asked on
>   [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/240019-why-is-this-curve-inverting-itself)
>   where a response says it may be a bug that was fixed in 10.6.1.
>   Product Engineer plans to contact OP.

to which the [asker replied](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/335740/why-did-curve-in-parcel-fabric-invert-itself?noredirect=1#comment547762_335740):

> ... yeah I posted there too! I got the DM this morning so I'll work with them to figure it out.